# How to run ffmpeg command in python; vscode?

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, command-prompt

i'd like to run this command

```
for /R %f IN (/*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%f" -f wav -bitexact -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 %~nf.wav
```

inside this script, like this:

```
import os
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
today = today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
dir_name = f"C:/Users/lucan/Automatically/{today}/"

def extract(user):
  test = os.listdir(dir_name)
  command = "for /R %f IN (/*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%f" -f wav -bitexact -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 %~nf.wav"
  os.system(command)
  for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".wav"):
      os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))


extract("businessbarista")
```

when i do so this is the error message I get:

> command = "for /R %f IN (/*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%f" -f wav -bitexact
> -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 %~nf.wav" TypeError: must be real number, not str

the command runs fine in command prompt, but not in powershell. can you help me figure out what went wrong?

Comment: As shown by both answers (as I write this) using `os.system` is almost always a mistake. Getting the quoting of arguments correct is difficult. Also, if you really need to execute arbitrary shell statements you should just create a shell script with those statements. Whether you should then have a Python program execute that script is an open question. But at least externalizing the shell script makes understanding, and debugging, such situations easier.

Answer (score 2):

Why mix Python & batch scripts?

If I understood the batch script for loop syntax, the following should be equivalent in Python:

```py
from glob import glob
import subprocess as sp
from os import path

# FFmpeg command (missing input & output)
cmd = ['ffmpeg','-i',None,'-f','wav','-bitexact','-acodec','pcm_s16le','-ar','22050','-ac','1']

# likely equivalent to 'for /R %f IN (/*.mp4) DO '
for input in glob("**/*.mp4",recursive=True): 
    cmd[3] = input
    output = path.splitext(input)[0] + '.wav'
    sp.run([*cmd,output])
```

This snippet scans the current folder and all its subfolders and lists all mp4 files in them and return the relative paths. e.g., `mp4\video.mp4`. Then `os.path.splitext()` removes the file extension to form the output file path.

Answer (score 1):

You have `" "` inside `" "` and this makes problem.

It treats it as two strings `"first" %f "second"`.

You have to replace one pair of `" "` with `' '` - like `' " " '` or `" ' ' "`.

Or you have to use `\` like `" \" \" "`

```
command = 'for /R %f IN (/*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%f" -f wav -bitexact -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 %~nf.wav'
```